# Index with groupby PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

I'm trying to translate the below pandas code to PySpark. But I'm having trouble with these two points:

- But there is index in Spark DataFrame?
- How can I group in level=0 like that?

I didn't find anything good in the documentation. If you have a hint, I'll be really grateful!

```
df.set_index('var1', inplace=True)
df['varGrouped'] = df.groupby(level=0)['var2'].min()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas_df.groupby(level=0)` would group the `pandas_df` by the first index field (in case of multiindex data). Since there is only 1 index field based on the provided code, your code is a simple group by the `var1` field. The same can be replicated in pyspark with a `groupBy()` and taking the `min` of `var2`.

However, the aggregation result is stored in a new column within the same dataframe. So, the number of rows don't depreciate. This can be replicated by using `min` [window function](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-window-functions/).

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('grouped_var', func.min('var2').over(wd.partitionBy('var1')))
```

`withColumn` helps you add/replace columns.

---

Here's an example using sample data.

```py
data_sdf.show()

# +---+---+
# |  a|  b|
# +---+---+
# |  1|  2|
# |  1|  3|
# |  2|  5|
# |  2|  4|
# +---+---+

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('grouped_res', func.min('b').over(wd.partitionBy('a'))). \
    show()

# +---+---+-----------+
# |  a|  b|grouped_res|
# +---+---+-----------+
# |  1|  2|          2|
# |  1|  3|          2|
# |  2|  5|          4|
# |  2|  4|          4|
# +---+---+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

> But there is index in Spark DataFrame?

i think the index in pandas doesn't exist in spark since spark is not designed to do row level manipulation.

> How can I group in level=0 like that?

instead of group by level, you group directly by the columns which identifies the granularity level.